# need explanation of what exactly is a directrix & focus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

((I'm not asking why do we need to know conic sections etc.) Like other similar questions.) I actually love math & currently learning conic sections in class, neither my textbook or teacher explain exactly what a directrix is? I just don't understand how to find it from $y=-2x^{2}$? my book says it's a fixed line equidistant from set all points that make up a parabola. But I don't get how do we know where the line is & why is it specifically located there & not 1unit up/down?  plz if anyone could explain the logic? , I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WRQsu59DdI) will help.  I am sure there are other decent videos about this too, but I did not search too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points of the conic are equidistant from the directrix and the focal point.
Suppose the focal point is at $(0,-f)$ then the directrix should be at $y=f$ so that the tip of parabola will be equidistant from both.

Now consider a point $(x,-2x^2)$ on the parabola. Find its distance form the focus and the directrix and set them equal.

From the directrix the distance is $f+2x^2$.

From the focus the distance is $\sqrt{x^2+(f-2x^2)^2}$

Now set these equal and solve for $f$. You will get $f=1/8$. So the directix is at $y=1/8$ and the focus at $(0,-1/8)$.

Comment: OK well my textbook says focus=(h, k+p)...now I know what h is But what is p & how do I find that?

Comment: I suppose $(h,k)$ is the tip of the parabola which here is at $(0,0)$. For ellipse and hyperbola $(h,k)$ is the center of the figure.

Comment: I am guessing the formula you mentioned from your book is for parabola opening up. There are probably 4 formulas in your book , for  up/down/left/right opening types. This one opens down so focus is at $(h,k-p)$.

Comment: yeah that's is for opening up & it shows all four.. but like a problem on my hw asks to find vertex, focus, directrix for (y=-2x^2)..to find focus do get rid of the - 2(coefficient)?  by multiplying it by - (1/2)?

Comment: For a down parabola $(y-k)=-(1/4p) (x-h)^2$.  Note $h$ and $k$ are the quantities subtracted from $x,y$ in the standard formula, they make the parabola move around; and the focus and directrix also move with them. Here $h=0,k=0$. You may want to check the movies in [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/conics_precalc/parabolas_precalc/v/parabola-focus-and-directrix-1) for more detail.